# Check All not working

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

```
//toggle check all

$("#bill-all").click(function(){

    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){

        $('.bill_fillter').prop('checked', true);

    } else {

        $('.bill_fillter').prop('checked', false);

    }

});
```

Html:Code
If i check here.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="all" id="bill-all" />
```

Check All is not working, nothing gonna checked if i checked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bill_<?php echo($i);?>" report_date="<?php echo $a1[1]; ?>" value="<?php echo($unit_id);?>" class="bill_fillter" id="bill-all"/>
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for [Check Box Check/Uncheck All](http://jsfiddle.net/oa33m0k0/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#bill-all").click(function(){

   if( $(this).is(":checked") )
     $(".bill_filter").prop('checked', true);
   else 
     $(".bill_filter").prop('checked', false);

});
```

Comment: And where does your example enhance anything? `$('.bill-filter')` is already a group selection, meaning any function called on the group applies to all elements within the group. Iteration therefor is overhead.

Comment: Is it still not possible to explain the difference from your answer to the question asked? the class `bill-fillter` is not even used, it's using an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `id` form -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bill_<?php echo($i);?>" report_date="<?php echo $a1[1]; ?>" value="<?php echo($unit_id);?>" class="bill_fillter" id="bill-all"/>
```

Try with -

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bill_<?php echo($i);?>" report_date="<?php echo $a1[1]; ?>" value="<?php echo($unit_id);?>" class="bill_fillter"/>
```

Sample -

```
   <input type="checkbox" name="bill"   class="bill_fillter" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="bill"   class="bill_fillter" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="bill"   class="bill_fillter" />
   <hr />
   <input type="checkbox" name="all" id="bill-all" />
```

Script -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bill-all").click(function(){

    if( $(this).is(":checked") ){

        $('.bill_fillter').prop('checked', true);

    } else {

        $('.bill_fillter').prop('checked', false);

    }

});
```

Comment: Your code is working for me. Can you show the rendered html and check the console for any error??

Comment: which is should use class="bill_fillter"  or id="bill-all"

Comment: you should use `class` for the checkboxes you want to be checked.

Comment: It need to remove the `id` from the checkboxes which is going to be checked & unchecked, not the the one onwhich the click event will work

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your not binding the click event on document ready.

Given the HTML as an example

```
<input type="checkbox" id="bill-all" /><br /><br />

<input type="checkbox" class="bill_filter" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="bill_filter" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="bill_filter" />
```

The javascript code needs to be executed when the DOM (document) is ready, e.g. all HTML elements are *available*.

```
  $(function() {
    $('#bill-all').click(function() {
      $('.bill_filter').prop("checked", $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
  });
```